# Retrieving records from a table within two date variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which I want to query records from based on a timescale between two dates.

I have two variables,

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime;
DECLARE @EndDate datetime;
```

What clause could I add to only show the records found within dates applied to these two variables?

This is based on a 'Date' column within the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT myColumn
  FROM myTable
 WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Edited: Between clause is `inclusive` (both dates are included in the result) so if you maybe want to exclude one of the dates in the variable columns better use:

```
SELECT myColumn
  FROM myTable
 WHERE Date >= @StartDate
   AND Date <= @EndDate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM [your_table] WHERE Date>=@StartDate AND Date<=@EndDate
```